# Java any way to keep a method usable only by class and subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am fully aware of how `public`, `protected` and `private` in Java work. I was wondering if there is a way to mimic a modifier in between private and protected. I want only a class and its children to be able to access its children.

I want to do this because I have a class, `Savable` that stores an `int databaseID`. `Savable` has a `save()` method that stores the DBID then calls `protected abstract ContentValues getSaveData ()` to obtain any other information from its children to write into the DB. This however, is unsafe design. `ContentValues` will store all of the objects information, private or not to be written into the DB.

Now, while I could just make save an abstract method in `Savable`, I would prefer to keep the structure I have now, as I will be adding data to the `Savable` class later on, and I would prefer to never have to expose this data to the user.

So, is there any way to mimic a children-only modifier in Java? If not, I may store the encrypted value of all the data the user supplies in `getSaveData()`.

Requested code: Removed as it is no longer necessary.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide some code to show what kind of behavior you expect, and what kind of behavior you wish to avoid, and how you expect encryption to solve it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I will post code. It is Android specific, so I will need to modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, is there any way to mimic a children-only modifier in Java?

Nope. The only access modifiers we've got are the ones you listed. There's also "default" visibility, aka "package-private", but that does not make elements accessible to subclasses. So you could probably just use `protected` and not worry about it.

It sounds like a better solution might be a refactor of your code, but there's not much concrete in your question to go on.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think is to make the method `protected`, and put the class in its own package.

Comment: Of course, that does not truly stop someone from accessing your `protected` elements from their code – just harder.

Comment: @MattBall well, no. But I find the requirement somewhat dubious anyway.

Comment: Could an attacker not inject its own class that extends Savable into the package? That would trick the system if I relied on it.

Comment: @Andy Turner, Why do you say the requirement is dubious?

Comment: @AndrewNo access modifiers are not a security measure. They don't prevent attacks. They are merely a programming tool, that helps your compiler prevent you from writing certain types of bad code.

Comment: @AndrewNo in a tautological sense, because it's not something that Java supports, so it's not something you should look to do. As MattBall suggests, the design isn't right currently. Why wouldn't the attacker just create a subclass to do their nefarious deeds, if that is allowed?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I was taught both in and out of school that you should make everything private that can be made private. Private methods may not prevent attacks, but there's no reason to make it easier for an attacker with a public modifier.

Comment: @AndyTurner May I ask you to elaborate on the problem you have with the design? I am posting code right now as it as requested.

Comment: @AndrewNo "Why wouldn't the attacker just create a subclass to do their nefarious deeds, if that is allowed?". You may have missed that, I edited the comment.

Comment: @AndrewNo Again, you are mixing your domains. There is no reason to make it easy for your software to be broken by exposing implementation as part of the contract (which is what happens when you mark something that is supposed to be private as public). It has nothing to do with security.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291022/security-impact-of-access-modifiers-public-private-internal-protected) for example.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Fair point. Marking classes as final would however prevent this, and I have done that.

Comment: If the class is `final`, just make the method `private`. There can be no subclasses.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, That's perfect. I am unsure how I was unaware of that.

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant I would mark all of its children final.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have already acknowledged my bad design lol. I will be reworking it. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you yourself are writing the children then you could make them `final`.

Mixing this up with the `protected` modifier would give you something like what you want.